# Filter D3 multidimensional array by another array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 but not JQuery.

I have an array of airports in nations participating in the World Cup:

```
d3.csv("output4.csv",
    function(data) {return {airports: d.Airports, country: data.Country, cup: data.WorldCupGroup }},
    function(data) {
    var new_array = data.map(function (d) {return [d.country, d.cup, d.timezone]}); 
    // D3 attributes added here
    });
```

My users will click a dropdown menu and select "World Cup Group" A through H, and I want my data in d.country to filter to only those groups and then render only those groups' airports in my dashboard.

I'm storing what the user has selected in

```
var cupsArray = [];
var cupChecks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked.CupGroup')
for (var i = 0; i < cupChecks.length; i++) {
    cupsArray.push(cupChecks[i].value);
}
```

directly above that so that I don't have to use any global variables (the D3.csv function is nested inside an updating function).

If the user has only selected one checkbox, I only have to do

```
new_array.filter(function(d) { return d[0] == cupsArray})
```

But if they select more than one, the code fails.

If the user has selected, say, two, then I can do:

```
var new_array = new_array.filter( function(d) {return d[0] == cupsArray[0] || d[0] == cupsArray[1]})
```

but obviously doing that for all 8 possible checkboxes for World Cup groups would be criminal.

I've tried things like

```
var new_array = new_array.filter( function(d, i) {return d[5] == cocomArray[i] })
```

But there's nothing giving it an "or" logic there, so it returns every row. How can I return "x number" of filters from my data?

Data sample:

```
Airport_name    Country WorldCupGroup
Arrabury Airport    Australia   C
El Arish International Airport  Egypt   A
Arapoti Airport Brazil  E
Merzbrück Airport   Germany F
Arraias Airport Brazil  E
Aalborg Airport Denmark C
Anapa Airport   Russia  A
Aarhus Airport  Denmark C
Araxá Airport   Brazil  E
```

Comment: You could use the crossfilter library, that helps with filtering and sorting data across multiple dimensions. http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

Comment: Going forward I'll have to check this out. I've seen it elsewhere, definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you should be able to use [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for this.
Perhaps something along the lines of this:

```
var new_array = new_array.filter(function(d, i) { return cupsArray.indexOf( d[0] ) >= 0; })
```

It .indexOf will return -1 if the value (in this case d[0]) is not found in the array (in this case cupsArray).

Comment: I think you need to change d[i] in this to d[0]?

Comment: That did it! Worked right away. I had actually attempted to use indexOf prior to posting but adding i to function(d,i) to reference the cupsArray members never occurred to me.